# Moving past the cursor in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, cursor, text-cursor

[image]

I want to write in the space (which I have marked in red) beside the picture in Microsoft Word. However, the cursor is just stuck at the bottom, beside the picture. Is there anyway I can utilize the space beside the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a TextBox by going to the Insert tab then to the Test menu and choose TextBox. You can size and position this where you like.

*Note: Your menu may look different as I am using 2010.*

[image]

Comment: The menu looks the same in mine.

Answer (score 4):

You can adjust how the text wraps around the picture.

[image]

1. If the picture or object is on a drawing canvas, select the canvas. If the picture or object is not on a drawing canvas, select the picture or object.
2. On the *Format* tab, in the *Arrange* group, click **Position**.
   If the Arrange group is collapsed and Position isn't visible, click the Arrange button, and then click Position.
3. Click the wrapping position that you want to apply.

More info here: [Wrap text in Word 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/word-help/wrap-text-in-word-2007-HA010099740.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

While I prefer @techie007 answer, I discovered "[Click and Type](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/about-click-and-type-HP005257639.aspx?CTT=1)" also work.

[Just double click on the empty area and type to insert text](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/use-click-and-type-to-insert-text-and-graphics-HP005257640.aspx?CTT=1)

If it doesn't work, make sure the feature is enabled. In Word 2007/2010, Click File > Options > Advanced and Check "Enable click and type" and OK. See more in [Troubleshoot Click and Type](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/troubleshoot-click-and-type-HP005257823.aspx?CTT=1)

Comment: Just to clarify what's going on behind the scenes with this function, a tab stop is added to the paragraph at the location where the cursor is clicked.